# defaultCalendarForNewEvents is defined as optional however can't use optional binding to check if it's nil

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, eventkit, ekeventstore

I'm adding new functionality in my app, which is the ability to add an event in the default calendar set up on the phone. I get the permission and am ready to add the event. I check to see if there is an actual default calendar, but I get the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'EKCalendar'

Now, `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` is an `Optional` (see definition below) and it should be perfectly fine to use optional binding to check if it's nil or not. What am I missing?

`defaultCalendarForNewEvents` definition in EKEventStore.h:

```
open var defaultCalendarForNewEvents: EKCalendar? { get }
```

I'm using Swift 3 on iOS11.2.(Edited to correct the Swift version I'm using.)

Here's the code:

```
if let defaultCalendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents { <-- error line
    newEvent.title = "Some Event Name"
    newEvent.startDate = Date()
    newEvent.endDate = Date()
}
```

Comment: Added additional formatting for error message and class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question at the Swift discussion forum at swift.org and got a response. So as per the response, 'defaultCalendarForNewEvents' was marked non-optional in Swift 3 by accident and that was fixed in Swift 4. That's why there was a discrepancy: documentation showing declaration in Swift 4 but optional binding failing as I'm on Swift 3. Hope this helps someone who is having the same issue.

I was also told that this issue was not release-noted as it was a minor update.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` is not, in fact, an Optional.  Perhaps there is some nil-coalescing or something else happening that is not visible to you.  Regardless, if the compiler is telling you it's not optional there's no need to fight for optional binding.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, doesn't the compiler look at the declaration of a property to determine its type? If so, it shouldn't complain about the optional binding. @creeperspeak

Comment: I agree!  I guess I'm just thinking there must be something happening behind the scenes that you aren't aware of.